# How can I manage duplicate methods for multiple models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

For example, I would like to have a method name 'owner' which returns the owner of the article or comment on two models, Article, and Comment.
Rather than adding

```
def owner
    user
end
```

to every model, is there a way to manage multiple models with 1 method?

Comment: If this method in particular is what you want to add, it might make more sense to rename your associations to be owner instead of user.  Or maybe 'author' and 'commenter'

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to handle this:

1. include a module containing the method in each model
2. add the instance method to the `ActiveRecord` Base
3. add a `method_missing` which is more or less the same principle as above but a bit more hacky

The pros of 1 is that it includes the method only in the model you want but yo have to include a line...

The pros of 2 & 3 is that you'll have no need to include the module but every model will have it, even if not relevant.